# Connecting to Windows Home Network Printer

Tags: printing, workgroup

I have a Brother MFC 5440CN connected to my Windows Vista Desktop which is shared with the Workgroup. I have figured out how to go to the Printers application and find the shared printer. However, no driver is listed for my specific printer, although there are drivers for other Brother MFC printers. I tried downloading from the Brother website but don't know which to choose and how to install.

How do I install the correct drivers for my printer?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you include a picture of where the place where the driver should be listed?

Comment: Sorry, I am not at home right now.  If I got to printers, add printer, then find windows printer.  It comes up with workgroup, then list the PC, then the printer.  When I click okay on the printer is comes up with the dropdown menu for printers, there are several Brother MFC listed, just not mine.

Comment: Okay, that makes it more clear - no picture needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Ubuntu doesn't come with drivers for your printer. Using the built-in search feature doesn't come up with any results either.

Try following these [instructions for installing the printer drivers](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn1a.html).

Here is the [webpage](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-5440CN) to download the driver for your printer (use the CUPS version).

From the [community documentation's list of Brother printers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrintersBrother), your printer is listed:

> MFC-5440CN
>   Official Brother LPR ver 1.0.2-1, Cupswrapper ver 1.0.2-3 drivers
>   v8.04.4 (Hardy)
>   Followed Brother instructions, needed to mkdir /usr/share/cups/MFC5440CN and mkdir /var/spool/lpd/MFC5440CN, needed to install C-shell first

You might need to follow the extra steps listed, I'm not sure if they are still needed.
If you need to install the C-shell, you can do so by using `sudo apt-get install csh`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.  It's no biggie if I can't get it to work, but it would be more convenient.

Comment: @Maggie did this work? If so, please mark my answer as your accepted answer.

Comment: @ mspencer, sorry, I did not know I was supposed to mark your answer. It installed the printer locally on the laptop but the print driver still does not show up when I try to connect the network printer.  Maybe because the PC the printer is physically installed on is a Windows Vista.  Thanks for your help, though, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Maggie If this doesn't completely solve your problem and you still want to find a correct answer, you can unselect my answer as your accepted answer so people know you're still looking for a solution. (To unselect my answer, just click the checkmark again). Sorry my answer doesn't completely solve your problem, I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: It's okay, thanks, I don't need the printer, it would have been more convenient, that's all.